# Why does a Node.js Buffer have a fixed size?

Tags: node.js

From Node.js' `Buffer` [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html):

> The size of the Buffer is established when it is created and cannot be
>   resized.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm speculating here, but this is quite common. Strings often have a fixed length too (immutable).

If they didn't, the program would have to overallocate memory to accomodate for any extra bytes you might append later.

It's trivial to "resize" the buffer yourself by [copying](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_copy_target_targetstart_sourcestart_sourceend) it into a new one or via `Buffer.concat`.